# UPDATE Table with Distinct IDs but Same DisplayNum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called tblData with the following data.

Before Query:

```
   ID DisplayNum   Called
    1     A1        NULL
    2     A1        NULL
    3     A1        NULL
    4     B4        NULL
    5     B4        NULL
```

I have now:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) tblData SET Called = GETDATE() WHERE DisplayNum = @DisplayNo AND Called IS NULL

ID DisplayNum   Called
1     A1        7/1/2013 9:00 AM
2     A1        7/1/2013 9:00 AM
3     A1        7/1/2013 9:00 AM
4     B4        7/1/2013 9:30 AM
5     B4        7/1/2013 9:30 AM
```

I want just to update that top record where called is null for that particular DisplayNum

```
ID DisplayNum   Called
1     A1        7/1/2013 9:00 AM
2     A1        7/1/2013 9:05 AM
3     A1        7/1/2013 9:08 AM
4     B4        7/1/2013 9:20 AM
5     B4        7/1/2013 9:26 AM
```

How do I get it when is distinct ID for that particular group?

Comment: My guess would be you should rather put ID in your where clause instead of DisplayNum

Comment: Your code works as expected: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e363d/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e363d/3)

Comment: That UPDATE should not update all rows...

Comment: Where and how many times do you call the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: What do you mean with top record? The minumum ID with the same display number?

Answer (score 1):

Did I get it right that you want to update the record with the lowest ID that still satisfies your WHERE condition?

Try

```
UPDATE tblData 
  SET Called = GETDATE() 
  WHERE DisplayNum = @DisplayNo AND Called IS NULL
    AND ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tblData WHERE DisplayNum = 'A1' AND Called IS NULL ORDER BY ID ASC)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update  a 
set a.Called = GETDATE() 
from tblData a join (select min(ID) ID, DisplayNum 
                     from test
                     group by DisplayNum) b 
on (a.ID = b.ID and a.DisplayNum = b.DisplayNum)
where a.Called is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE T
SET Called = GETDATE()
FROM tblData T
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY DisplayNum ORDER BY ID) correlative
         FROM tblData
         WHERE Called IS NULL AND DisplayNum = @DisplayNo) TD ON T.ID=TD.ID
WHERE TD.correlative=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current information in the question, there should be no problem (unless you call the `UPDATE` multiple times). Here's a deom on  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e363d/3).

Here's a way to perform the update without using `TOP`:

```
DECLARE @@DisplayNo varchar(2)
SELECT @@DisplayNo = 'A1'

;WITH tblRN AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DisplayNum 
                      ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
  FROM tblData
)

UPDATE tblRN
  SET CALLED = GETDATE()
WHERE
  DisplayNum = @@DisplayNo AND
  CALLED IS NULL AND
  RowNum = 1
```